# Set the custom value of the aria-label on a Google chart

Tags: javascript, svg, google-visualization, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm using Google Chart's javascript library to build some charts and I wanted to improve their accessibility. My charts are currently being rendered with the ARIA tag attribute like this:

```
<svg width="500" height="500" aria-label="A chart." style="overflow: hidden;">
```

It's kind of a default value. I was wondering if anyone knows how to set a custom value for that attribute through the chart configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are no config options for setting attributes on the chart elements.
but you could manually change the attribute on the chart's `'ready'` event...

```
// set attribute
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
  var svg = chart.getContainer().getElementsByTagName('svg');
  if (svg.length > 0) {
    svg[0].setAttribute('aria-label', 'CUSTOM LABEL');
  }
});
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y');

  for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    data.addRow([i, ((2 * i) + (((i % 2) === 0) ? i * 2 : i * -2))]);
  }

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      left: 64,
      top: 48,
      right: 32,
      bottom: 48,
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%'
    },
    height: '100%',
    legend: {
      alignment: 'start',
      position: 'top'
    },
    width: '100%'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));

  // set attribute
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var svg = chart.getContainer().getElementsByTagName('svg');
    if (svg.length > 0) {
      svg[0].setAttribute('aria-label', 'CUSTOM LABEL');
      console.log(svg[0].outerHTML.substring(0, svg[0].outerHTML.indexOf('>') + 1));
    }
  });

  window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    chart.draw(data, options);
  });
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#chart {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Just as a heads up this won't quite work, the containing div has an `aria-label` that says "A chart". You need to remove that or some screen readers will read that out, most will ignore it as it is on a non-interactive element but for maximum usability I thought I would point that out.